# Convergence of iteration $x_{k+1}=\alpha_kx_k+(1-\alpha_k)z_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{z_k\}_{k=0}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ converges and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-\alpha_k^2)=+\infty$ with $\alpha_k\in[-1,1]$, can we prove that for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, iteration
$$
x_{k+1}=\alpha_kx_k+(1-\alpha_k)z_k,
$$
also converges to the same limit of $\{z_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$?

**Attemps** So far I have that if $\alpha_k\equiv\alpha\in(-1,1)$ then the conclusion holds, or if $z_k\equiv z$ then the conclusion also holds. I'm not sure if the general statement is actually true. Can we prove or disprove this?

Comment: What's the reason behind that particular hypothesis? I mean, I'm basically asking for a source or a motivation behind coming up with that particular criterion $\sum (1-\alpha_k^2) = +\infty$ if you came up with it yourself.

Comment: Actually the condition $\sum_{k}(1-\alpha_k^2)=\infty$ is needed for the convergence of $\{z_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, and it is not quite relevant to this problem. I make such guess after I found that $\sum_{k}(1-\alpha_k^2)=\infty$ is sufficient for $\prod_k|\alpha_k|=0$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks , I didn't quite understand where the condition came from, but perhaps it can be relaxed a little as long as a sufficient condition is obtained, I presume.